# How to reason about IntelliJ's hints about a Java 8 Lambda Expression?

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, java-8, anonymous-inner-class

Consider the following code in a Java method:

```
public void doWork() {
    Runnable runner1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(toString());
        }
    };
    new Thread(runner1).start();
}
```

When I hover my mouse over `new Runnable`, IntelliJ does the following:

[image]

that is, it gives me a choice to convert this snippet into a lambda expression.

The moment I change the `run()` method to reference the `this`, I forgo this capability, however:

[image]

I think I vaguely understand what is going on (effective finality of variables in the scope of a lambda expression), but wanted to get a more thorough answer about interchangeability of anonymous inner classes and lambda expressions.

#### Update After [Hank D's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595396/437506)

I agree with your assessment about the `this` reference assignment, but
let's look at the behavior of the program in the case where IntelliJ thinks that the anonymous inner class can be replaced by (an equivalent) lambda expression. Thus, I run this method (my outer class's name is `LambdaScope`):

```
public void doWork() {
    Runnable runner1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(toString());
        }
    };
    new Thread(runner1).start();
}
```

and it produces the following output (it clearly comes from the `toString()` method that this anonymous inner class inherits from `Object`):

```
LambdaScope$1@7a88bb53
```

When I choose the take IntelliJ's suggestion and convert the anonymous inner class into lambda expression, it becomes:

```
public void doWork() {
    Runnable runner1 = () -> System.out.println(toString());
    new Thread(runner1).start();
}
```

Running this method produces the following (I have overridden the method `toString()` in the outer class):

```
Outer class: class LambdaScope
```

I think this is a change in behavior. Is this a bug then?

Here's the complete example (you could open it in the IDE and try to recreate my steps to see my confusion):

```
public class LambdaScope {
    public void doWork() {
        Runnable runner1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(toString());
            }
        };
        new Thread(runner1).start();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Outer class: " + this.getClass();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LambdaScope ls = new LambdaScope();
        ls.doWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with information from JLS that I hope will clarify why it's doing that

Answer (score 3):

It probably shies away from it because the meaning of `this` is different in a lambda vs. an anonymous class.  In your anonymous class, `this` refers to the instance of `Runnable` you are creating, while in a lambda, `this` would refer to the object of which `doWork` is a member. Because an automatic conversion would change the behavior, it doesn't suggest the change.

In [JLS 15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2), it says,

> Unlike code appearing in anonymous class declarations, the meaning of names and the this and super keywords appearing in a lambda body, along with the accessibility of referenced declarations, are the same as in the surrounding context

That holds true whether you refer to `this` explicitly as in `this.toString()` or implicitly as in a call to `toString()`.

The JLS says a little later on,

> Practically speaking, it is unusual for a lambda expression to need to talk about itself (either to call itself recursively or to invoke its other methods), while it is more common to want to use names to refer to things in the enclosing class that would otherwise be shadowed (this, toString()). If it is necessary for a lambda expression to refer to itself (as if via this), a method reference or an anonymous inner class should be used instead.

So, as I hope you will see from the JSL documentation, the behavior you are seeing is not a bug, and IntelliJ is correct not to offer the transformation, because the behavior would change.

Comment: To be more specific, it is *impossible* to create an equivalent lambda expression, as a lambda expression can’t access the `Runnable` instance created for it. I salute IntelliJ for recognizing this beforehand rather than just offering a conversion and transforming pattern-based.

Comment: Hank, I like your answer, but I can't yet accept it because I believe it is a bug in IntelliJ ;).

Comment: @KedarMhaswade: HankD's answer is completely correct in describing why it doesn't suggest a conversion for the second case. You are saying that the first case is a bug. That doesn't contradict any part of HankD's answer.

Comment: I hoped to convey that whereas I understand now "why it doesn't suggest a conversion for the second case", it's not clear how the suggestion it offers in the first case is correct. I am not convinced yet that the conversion made by the IDE (upon choosing to let it convert) is equivalent (since it produces a different output).

Comment: I can see similar behaviour in Eclipse: reject the conversion if explicit `this` is found, but ignore the implicit `this`. Apparently, analysis in both tools is incomplete for the implicit case. At least Eclipse rejects the conversion if you change `toString()` to `this.toString()`. I'd assume IntelliJ does the same. I just wonder, if considering all implicit `this` references would be a practical strategy...